# Highlighting text affecting page numbers in Latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

So I am writing an assignment in Latex. As part of this assignment, I have to highlight various pieces of writing in different colours according to theme.
After researching, I have used the soul and colour packages.
I couldn't get it to behave nicely also highlighting references in my text until I 
found a hacky solution on here:

```
\usepackage{soul}
\soulregister\cite7
\soulregister\ref7
\soulregister\pageref7
\usepackage{color}
```

The only problem now is this is affecting the page numbers where text is highlighted. The first page where highlighting occurs is now set to page 0 (despite previously being page 8). When a different colour is used, that page is set to page 0.

I somewhat suspect it is related to the \pageref7 command, but I have used that to play nicely with my citations. Is there a way I can fix this?

EDIT: MINIMAL WORKING DOCUMENT CODE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{authordate1-4}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{soul}
\soulregister\cite7
\soulregister\ref7
\soulregister\pageref7
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{html}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{harvard}
%\renewcommand{\harvardurl}{URL: \url}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.60}\normalsize
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendices}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{ {\sethlcolor{#1} \hl{#2}} }
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\tableofcontents
%\listoffigures
%\listoftables
%\title{Minimal}
%\author{RG}
%\date{April 2013}
%\maketitle

%\input{./title.tex}


\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\pagenumbering{arabic}

This is a sample unhighlighted piece of writing.

\hlc[green]{This is a sample piece of highlighted writing.}

\bibliographystyle{authordate1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's difficult to analyse what might be going on here. I would suggest you post what is called a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Click on the link and read the post. You should provide code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` so we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and replicate your current problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. MWE added above. :)

Comment: I am facing the same problem!

Comment: I believe this might be the same problem as reported in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25250/156366).

Answer (score -1):

It is possible there is a command \hlc containing two paragraphs separated by a line break on the interface between two pages, that is:

\hlc{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
-------(end page)-----
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.
----(line break)----
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.}

You can avoid the error by:

\hlc{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
-------(end page)-----
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.}
----(line break)----
\hlc{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.}

Comment: Instead of bla bla, you can use lore ipsum generators